# Unable to make the combo box show password

Tags: php, html, laravel

i have a text field for password and i wanted to add a checkbox to show the password and it seemed to be not working im new to laravel.

```
{{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                <br>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#checkbox').on('change', function(){

                $('#password').attr('type',$('#checkbox').prop('checked')==true?"text":
                "password");
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: you should probably look at the generated html source to see if these form inputs have ids

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#checkbox').on('change', function(){
   $('#password').attr('type',$('#checkbox').prop('checked')==true?"text":"password"); 
   });
 });
 </script>
 <input type="password" id="password"> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">Show Password
```

You should give the inputs an ID
In your case :

```
{{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password']) }}
{{ Form::checkbox(null, null, false, ['id' => 'show-password']) }} Show Password
```

for your Javascript code you will add

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#show-password').on('change', function(){
       $('#password').prop('type', $(this).prop('checked') ? 'text' : 'password');
   });
});
```

**Note**

```
{{ Form::checkbox(null, null, false, ['id' => 'show-password']) }} Show Password
```

1. first `null` is the `name` of the checkbox
2. second `null` is the `value` of the checkbox
3. third `null` is the `checked` attribute of the checkbox it could be `true` of `false`